# Find number of sub-string in a string between two character(a*b) using python re module

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Given a string S as input. The program must find the number of patterns matching a*b. where * represent 1 or more alphabets.

```py
import re
s = input()
matches = re.findall(r'MAGIC',s)
print(len(matches))


'''
i/p - aghba34bayyb
o/p - 2
(i.e aghb,ayyb)
It should not take a34b in count.

i/p - aabb
o/p - 3
(i.e aab abb aabb)

i/p : adsbab 
o/p : 2 
(i.e adsb ab)'''
```

Comment: why in the 3rd example output is `2` why not `3` i.e `adsb, ab, adsbab` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the positions of `a` and `b` in the word, find all possible substrings and then filter the substrings that only contains one or more chars in between

```
from itertools import product

words = ['aghba34bayyb', 'aabb', 'adsbab']

for word in words:
    a_pos = [i for i,c in enumerate(word) if c=='a']
    b_pos = [i for i,c in enumerate(word) if c=='b']
    all_substrings = [word[s:e+1] for s,e in product(a_pos, b_pos) if e>s]
    substrings = [s for s in all_substrings if re.match(r'a[a-zA-Z]+b$', s)]
    print (word, substrings)
```

**Output**

```
aghba34bayyb ['aghb', 'ayyb']
aabb ['aab', 'aabb', 'abb']
adsbab ['adsb', 'adsbab']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
a[a-zA-Z]+?b
```

[image]

---

```
import re
s = input()
matches = re.findall(r'a[a-zA-Z]+?b',s)
print(len(matches))
```

[`Python Demo`](https://onlinegdb.com/HJp2EMxGS)

Comment: @Viky oh yes, fixed

Comment: For `s = 'aaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbb'` the result is `1` -- not sure if this is the correct number.

Comment: Hey pal! Still I got problem. I/p : adsbab  then o/p : 2 @Codemaniac (i.e adsb,ab)

Comment: @Viky [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OjZoOa/1/) it selects only one and as per rule last `ab` should not be selected right ?

Comment: Is that illustration the output of some nice regex diagramming tool? If so could you point me at it? Thx

Comment: @sparc_spread this is called regex visualizer [`Regulex`](https://jex.im/regulex/)

Comment: @Viky you should update your question accordingly and also add some example of possible inputs, will update answer accordingly

Comment: I updated my question @CodeManiac , Is this something like Lookahead ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.finditer` to match all substrings:

```
inputs = ['aghba34bayyb',
'aabb',
'adsbab']

import re

def all_substrings(s):
    length, seen = len(s), set()
    for i in range(length):
        for j in range(i + 1, length + 1):
            for g in re.finditer(r'(a[^\d]+b)', s[i:j]):
                if (i+g.start(), i+g.end()) in seen:
                    continue
                seen.add((i+g.start(), i+g.end()))
                yield g.groups()[0]

for i in inputs:
    print('Input="{}" Matches:'.format(i))
    for s in all_substrings(i):
        print(' "{}"'.format(s))
```

Prints:

```
Input="aghba34bayyb" Matches:
 "aghb"
 "ayyb"
Input="aabb" Matches:
 "aab"
 "aabb"
 "abb"
Input="adsbab" Matches:
 "adsb"
 "adsbab"
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
re.findall(r'a[A-Za-z]+?b',s)
```

Where

- `[A-Za-z]` matches an alphabetic character,
- `+` is one or more characters
- `?` tells it to be nongreedy

Answer (score 0):

You could match `a` followed by 1 char `a-z` and then use a character class matching 0+ times `a` or `c-z` and then match the first `b`

```
a[a-z][ac-z]*b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HxlnG2/1)

If you want to match all following b's to match `aabb` instead of `aab` you could use

```
a[a-z][ac-z]*b+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iSy1f4/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/c2tHPl)

```
import re
s = input()
matches = re.findall(r'a[a-z][ac-z]*b+',s)
print(len(matches))
```